# A Big Function with Case instead of many small functions

Tags: php, oop

The benefits of breaking code into very small components which do one and only one simple function are obvious. But there is nothing which mandates that we should make each and every function a separate function in itself.

Consider the following case:

- There is one big function, however EACH of the cases included in the function is isolated, and runs only by itself. All of the case blocks can be just copy/pasted into a different code body, wrapped in their function name. So its modular. **There wont be any multiple cases(ifs) combined, ever**.
- All the small functions which reside in the case blocks use $vars array as their main variable. So any number of variables in any format can be passed to the parent iterator as part of an array. There are no limitations.
- The parent iterator can be run anywhere, from any place, even within itself by requesting a particular action. ie $this->run_actions('close_ticket');
- It has massive advantage regarding the common procedures which need to be run, and may need to be run over all actions requested. output buffering is one, and any action hooks, filters or any other all encompassing system that can be imagined.
- This format allows any future new procedures which need be run before and after any action and/or on the inputs and outputs of any action, to be easily integrated. (**For the particular case i have in my hands, the appearance of such cases in future is certain!!!**.) If all these actions were divided into small functions instead, you would need to either go and change hooks and filters on each of the functions, or still have some sort of other function to dispatch these onto those small functions. With this format, you just place them before or after the switch/case block.
- Code reading is simple: When you see a particular case, you know what it does -> 'view_tickets' is the ticket view action, and it takes $vars as an input.

Obviously, a truly hypermassive function will have various disadvantages.

So, the question is:

**Assuming that the size of the function is kept at a reasonable size and the principles of modularity and one simple action per case is preserved, also considering that anyone who works with this code in future will not need to look into this code and must not modify this code and need to know only the hooks and filters which will be documented elsewhere than code itself, (including any variables they use) do you think this could be an efficient approach to combining tasks which need common procedures run on them?**

```
public function run_actions($action,$vars=false)
{

    // Global, common filters and procedures which all actions need or may need

    ob_start();

    switch($action)
    {

        case 'view_tickets':
        {
            // Do things
            // Echo things if necessary

            break;
        }
        case 'close_ticket':
        {
            // Do things
            // Echo things if necessary

            break;
        }
        case 'do_even_more_stuff':
        {
            // Do things
            // Echo things if necessary

            break;
        }
        // Many more cases as needed
    }

    // Even more common post-processing actions, filters and other stuff any action may need

    $output=ob_get_clean();

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to re-invent the Command Bus pattern. See for example http://shawnmc.cool/command-bus

Comment: The principle is similar, but the applications are not the same - though $vars array can be passed from command to command in the example in your reference, i dont want to haul around any variable or procedure which may be global to function, but not global across code.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace conditional with polymorphism. Create an abstract action class with a method like "execute" and then subclass for all various actions implementing that method.

e.g.

```
function run_actions(IAction action) {
    //...
    action->execute();
    //...
}
```

That way, if you will need to introduce additional behavior, you won't need to modify and test long run_actions with numerous responsibilities.

Comment: Dont have any long conditional. There wont be any cases of multiple cases being combined. Each case performs only one single, DIFFERENt action.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I don't know why I said long. But the idea I believe is still valid.

Comment: I actually ended up doing something like this by using magic function using __call. It ended up being something akin to front controller pattern. Have been using it for a while, and it has been very flexible and convenient. Every action can be hooked to before/after it runs, every input and output variable can be filtered. Has been very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Various disadvantages:

**The switch cases all use $vars so they don't have a specific signature.**

- This hides the signature from the developer that its thus forced to read the code.
- you can't do type-hinting on $vars (force parameters to be arrays, instance of some class, etc)
- no IDE autocompletion

**Easier to do a mistake**

- forget a `break` and you're done. No recognizable error.

**Difficult to refactor**

- what would you do if you need to extract the code to a function? You need to duplicate preprocessing (`ob_start`, etc) or to change everything
- what would you do if you needed to run on action with no preprocessing?

I agree it is very simple, but it has long-run disadvantages. Up to you to strike the right balance :)

Comment: "you can't do type-hinting on $vars" -> $vars is supposed to ALWAYS be an array. It will never be solely a single var, though it has the potential....."no IDE autocompletion" -> this depends on ide - mine completes any keyword visible in the code. "what would you do if you need to extract the code to a function?" -> copy the contents of the case, wrap it in its function name, thats it. its already listed, this one.

Comment: "what would you do if you needed to run on action with no preprocessing" -> leaving aside that in the particular use case in hand it will never happen, you can add a condition to apply or not apply the pre and postprocessing through dropping a variable into $vars array.

Comment: @unity100 Without further restriction "array" isn't a particularly useful piece of type information - a PHP array could be a container for literally any kind of data.

Comment: Look, your question is open-ended. If you was my co-worker I would not like to have that kind of code in the project. Still there are notable examples of similar approaches like for example http://rackt.github.io/redux/ (which goes way beyond, btw)

Comment: @IMSoP -> array is totally irrelevant and neutral in regard to any info on the variables contained here - you are supposed to check for $var['particularobject'] instead of expecting the particularobject as $var itself. ie, you must assume that $var will ALWAYS be an array.

Comment: @tacone -> "Look, your question is open-ended. If you was my co-worker I would not like to have that kind of code in the project" -> If this code was in the project, the code itself would have been totally transparent and irrelevant for you -> you would be expected to work only through the action  and filter hooks which are explained in the question. You would not need to see the core code, and you would be expected to not modify it, ever....... If you cant imagine such a case, imagine you are producing an addon/mod for a wordpress plugin.

Comment: @unity100 Yes, that's exactly my point. The array is not the argument, it's just a container for the real arguments. Where is the existence and type of `$var['particularobject']` documented, and where is it checked? Those are things the language can do for you with a real function argument.

Comment: @IMSoP "Where is the existence and type of $var['particularobject'] documented" -> maybe i should have added this point to the question. documentation will not be in the code at all, so the code is not expected to be self-descriptive or informative. ALL the people who will deal with this code (even including myself in future) need to know are the action hooks and filters. Any variable which is used by them, will be listed under the hook/filter's own documentation in a separate documentation, which will not be included in the code.

Comment: @unity100 So you expect to get this code 100% correct the first time, and never edit it, yet also expect the implementation to contain non-trivial code inside the switch statement that might otherwise be in its own function? That sounds optimistic to the point of naive!

Comment: @MSoP "So you expect to get this code 100% correct the first time, and never edit it" -> from time to time (occasionally) i may edit the code and add this or that. However this needs to be very rare. Even i myself am supposed to work through hooks and filters when extending this code, and it must be OUTSIDE this code. Basically this is the core of a wordpress plugin - must be VERY rarely edited/changed, and extension of functionality must come via addon plugins (totally separate from this code) through hooks, filters.

Comment: @unity100 It may surprise you, but WordPress is developed by humans, who have to understand and maintain that core code. They also have to write that external documentation, and check that it actually matches the code. If you write unreadable code because you think it will carry on working forever, you will come to regret it.

Comment: @IMSoP -> at this point im rather convinced that you lost the point. If im unable to remember my own code, which i will be working on constantly and add a simple functionality to its core when necessary despite the external documentation which will be existing, then i should just close up shop and scram on grounds of dementia. There is nothing unreadable in the code in that line, and actually its much better than trying to remember complex object inheritances, variable passing, and external includes. I believe we exhausted the productivity in this line of discussion, so im out - ty.

Comment: @unity100 You seem convinced that structure is your enemy, when an entire industry has built up around the opposite. At some point, you will leave this part of code alone for some time, then get a bug report; trust me that you will be thankful then for high-level structure that can be examined with standard tools rather than digging into your memory of how the magic flows.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94636/discussion-on-answer-by-tacone-a-big-function-with-case-instead-of-many-small-fu).

Answer (score 1):

When I look at this kind of architecture, I see it as beginning to build a new programming language on top of the existing one. This isn't always a bad thing, if the features you're building are a better abstraction than the language you're building them with, but it's worth challenging what those features are.

In this case, the part of the language you're reinventing is function dispatch: you have a named action, which takes arbitrary parameters, and runs arbitrary code. PHP already does this, and quite efficiently; it also has features your system lacks, such as built-in checks of the number and (to some extent) type of parameters. Furthermore, by inventing a non-standard "syntax", existing tools will not work as well - they won't recognise the actions as self-documenting structures, for instance.

The main part you gain is the ability to add pre- and post-processing around the actions. If there were no other way to achieve this, the tradeoff might be worthwhile, but luckily you have better options, e.g. putting each action into a function, and passing it as a callback to the wrapper function; or making each action an object, and using inheritance or composition to attach the pre- and post-processing without repeating it.

By wrapping the arguments in an array, you can also emulate named parameters, which PHP lacks. This can be a good idea if a function takes many parameters, some of them perhaps optional, but it does come with the drawbacks of reinventing processing that the language would normally do for you, such as applying the correct defaults, complaining on missing  mandatory items, etc

Comment: "The part you gain is the ability to add pre- and post-processing around the actions" -> thats the critical point of entire affair......... I need to refrain from any complex inheritance and variable passing schemes. it needs to be dead simple.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94637/discussion-on-answer-by-imsop-a-big-function-with-case-instead-of-many-small-fun).

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple principle that says don't use more than 2 tab indentation.

eg :

```
public function applyRules($rules){
    if($rules){
        foreach($rules as $rule){
            //apply ryle
        }
    }
}
```

Becomes better when you refactor it :

```
public function applyRules($rules){
    if($rules){
        $this->executeRules($rules);
    }
}

private function executeRules($rules){
    foreach($rules as $rule){
        $rule->execute();
    }
}
```

And this way your code will be refactored better and you could apply more unit tests than you could.

Another rule says don't use else, instead break the code eg :

```
public function usernameExists($username){
    if($username){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Instead of doing this, you should do this :

```
public function usernameExists($username){
    if($username){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Only this way you ensure that your code flows 100%